# Changing serial port baud rate in Win32 without transmitting

Tags: c++, winapi, arduino, serial-port

I'm new to serial programming, and am trying to make a program that sends bytes via the serial port to an Arduino, to control an LED array. For efficiency, I want to do this in C++ using the Windows API, with a high baud rate. Here's my minimal example which just sends a '1':

```
#include <windows.h>

DCB serialParams;
byte data[1];
DWORD bytessent;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    data[0] = 1;

    HANDLE arduino = CreateFile("/COM5", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

    serialParams.BaudRate = CBR_19200;
    serialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    serialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    serialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
    SetCommState(arduino, &serialParams);

    WriteFile(arduino, &data, 1, &bytessent, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

This works well, except that calling the SetCommState function seems to send a whole load of random data to the port, which is a headache to try to sort from the actual data coming through. Is there a way in Windows API to close the port temporarily while making the changes? This should be possible as it can be done pretty easily in Python with pySerial:

```
from serial import Serial
s = Serial("/COM5")
s.close()
s.baudrate = 18400
s.open()
s.write([1])
```

Comment: It's not possible,  I guess that Python simply sends the other DCB structure with defaults.

Comment: Please try 19200bps in the port setting of COM port control panel of device manager. These articles may be helpful. [How to Change Baud Rate for COM Port?](https://www.dell.com/community/Windows-General/How-to-Change-Baud-Rate-for-COM-Port/td-p/506488), [Windows 7: want to change a baud rate](https://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/136850-want-change-baud-rate.html), [The mythical port settings in Windows](https://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/FAQ_Adjusting_The_Serial_Port_Settings_In_Windows)  Maybe it depends on your hardware and device drivers.

Comment: How to determine "**SetCommState function seems to send a whole load of random data to the port**"? See it from oscilloscope？ Or arduino device receive something after just calling `SetCommState`?

Comment: You didn't initialize `serialParams.DCBlength` field, so probablly `SetCommState` just fails. Initialize `DCBlength`, call `GetCommState` to fill fields that you don't intent to change, check result code of `SetCommState`

Answer (score 1):

SetCommState shouldn't send any data to port.
But, if you try to change/set some values of DCB, you should get data from port (use GetCommState), change desired values, and set new dcb.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setcommstate
See "Remarks" section.